# Where do I put a method that is based on 2 models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a user model and point model. A user can have many points and points belong to users.

Users earn points and I am just not sure where I should put the methods for these models. For example, I want to have an "add_points" method that adds points to a user. I'm thinking that should go in the user model but i'm just not sure.

I want to be able to do user1.add_points(:earned_for, amount)

or something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the method to the user, you probably won't be doing much more than hooking into the `create` method of the `has_many` relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :points

  def add_point(reason, amount)
    points.create({:earned_for => reason, :amount => amount})
  end
end
```

If the shorthand is useful, great; otherwise, you might just use the helper methods that are defined in your relationships. See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) for the details.

Answer (score 0):

I would do as you have described

the user object can have a `add_points` method,placing anything on the point object doesn't make sense as a point object is there to represent an abstract concept were the user object is there to represent a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in this case you don't need any additional methods for adding points: as far as your User has_many :points you can add points for user this way:

```
@user.points.create earned_for: reason, amount: amount
```